# How to load more products automatically twice, then load more button

Tags: javascript, onscroll

Hi there lovely people!

I'm brand new in development world! HELLO!!
I'm trying to make an overwrite for a listing page with products. I want to achieve that it automatically shows more products on scroll, then again more products on scroll, and after that show a load more button.
This is the code that automatically shows more products on scroll:

```
if (
  (tc_vars.env_template === "list" ||
    tc_vars.env_template === "internal_search" ||
    tc_vars.env_template === "other_generic") &&
  document.querySelector(".more-content") !== null
) {

  var secondsclicked = 0;
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    var element = document.querySelector(".more-content");
    if (element !== null) {
      var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();

      // checking if cta visible
      if (position.top >= 0 && position.bottom <= window.innerHeight) {
        var d = new Date();
        var seconds = d.getSeconds();

        if (
          seconds !== secondsclicked &&
          document.querySelector(".more-content").parentElement.offsetHeight !==
            0
        ) {
          document.getElementById("more_product_a").click();
          secondsclicked = d.getSeconds();
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Is there a way to adjust this code and make it perform like described as above, so load more products on scroll twice, then load more button.
That would be amazing :)
Looking forward to your replies!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself! :)

```
if (
      (tc_vars.env_template === "list" ||
        tc_vars.env_template === "internal_search" ||
        tc_vars.env_template === "other_generic") &&
      document.querySelector(".more-content") !== null
    ) {
    
      let secondsclicked = 0;
      window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
        const products = document.getElementsByClassName("dkt-product");
        
        if (products.length >= 96) return;
        
        const element = document.querySelector(".more-content");
        if (element !== null) {
          const position = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    
          // checking if cta visible
          if (position.top >= 0 && position.bottom <= window.innerHeight) {
            const d = new Date();
            const seconds = d.getSeconds();
    
            if (
              seconds !== secondsclicked &&
              document.querySelector(".more-content").parentElement.offsetHeight !==
                0
            ) {
              document.getElementById("more_product_a").click();
              secondsclicked = d.getSeconds();
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Although it is a small code snippet, adding an explanation about where was the problem and what did you do to solve it will be helpful for future readers.